# 0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'module' is not defined

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am from a C++ background and have a day's experience in TypeScript. I am trying to implement a design (interface/class) that is split between multiple files. It is flashing runtime error : `0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'module' is not defined`

Info.ts

```
export = Test; <-----------   0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'module' is not defined
namespace Test {
    export class Info {
    }
}
```

TestWrapper.ts

```
import { Info } from "./Info";    
namespace Test {
    class TestWrapper {
        public GetInfo(): Info {
            return this.m_info;
        }
    }
}
```

Am I using something in the wrong way?

Comment: Just remove the `=` ...

Comment: After removing '=', it flashes error in call to import in TestWrapper.ts: 'File Info.ts' is not a module

Comment: No nested exports. Export a string, class, type, etc.

Comment: That's what I am doing, right? Exporting a class.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to export a namespace, not a class.  You declare the namespace "Test" but try to export it a line earlier.  What happens if you remove the `export = test`?

Answer (score 0):

A guess:

```
export = Something
```

Compiles to something like

```
module.exports = Something
```

`module.exports` is a construct of the so-called "commonjs module system", something that is not available in browsers, but in node.js. So if you run the generated code in a browser through a direct `<script>` import, it will bring an error like that. TS transpiles `imports` and `exports` to module systems that can be specified in the tsconfig.json, but TS itself is not responsible for implementing the module system.

What to do?

If this code is really supposed to run in the browser, you could opt on one of the 2 following options:

- Run the code through a *module bundler* (webpack), which will generate a browser compatible "bundle" (a big JS) concatenating all your files. Webpack has ways of including typescript as a plugin, so that you dont need to make your "build" a 2-step process; Module bundlers are usually fairly complicated.
- Make your files module-less (which means: no top-levem imports or exports) and import them through vanilla `<script>` tags.

Comment: Good guess, but actually it would work without the namespaces

Answer (score 0):

> Am I using something in the wrong way?

While `namespace`s are commonly used in other languages, they do not exist in JavaScript, so the typescript version is just some rarely used way to add proper typing to some things (I never used it yet). In your case you actually don't need a namespace. Just:

```
 export default class Info { /*...*/ }
```

Then you can

```
import Info from ".Info";

export default class TestWrapper { /*...*/ }
```

*PS: That said, I actually don't know how to make this work with namespaces to resolve the error*

Comment: But we're talking about **TypeScript** in which namespaces **do** exist: [Namespaces](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html).

Comment: @zero298 might read again: `so the typescript version is just some rarely used way to add proper typing to some things` ... Have you ever used them in Typescript?

Comment: I'm wrong, if you make an edit to your post, I'll get rid of my downvote.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to mix [modules](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html) and [namespaces](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html).  I would suggest reading [Namespaces and Modules](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces-and-modules.html).

You don't need to to `export` at the top level using `export = Test`, you also shouldn't `import { Info } from "./Info";` because `Info` is part of the `Test` namespace which `TestWrapper` is a member of.

If you want to go the namespace route, consider:

**Info.ts**

```
namespace Test {
    export class Info {}
}
```

**TestWrapper.ts**

```
namespace Test {
    export class TestWrapper {
        m_info: Info;
        public GetInfo(): Info {
            return this.m_info;
        }
    }
}
```

**Consumer.ts**

```
console.log(Test.TestWrapper);
```

Compile this using:

```
tsc --outFile foo.js Info.ts TestWrapper.ts Consumer.ts
```

Then run using:

```
node foo.js
```

Which prints:

```
[Function: TestWrapper]
```